# Kann "näher" als Präposition oder Adverb verwendet werden?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

"Näher" ist, glaube ich, ein Ajektiv und vielleicht auch ein Adverb.

Der Satz "Stell die Blumenvase näher an die Mitte vom Tisch" glaube ich korrekt sei.

Könnte man aber "näher" direkt als Präposition verwenden? Wenn so, mit welchem Kasus sollte man es verwenden?

Wäre "Stell die Blumen näher der/die Mitte..." möglich?

Oder als Adverb: "Stell die Blumen der/die Mitte näher" ?

Comment: *Näher* kann je nach Satz theoretisch beides sein, in der Regel ist es aber ein Adverb (und das Adjektiv *näherer/nähere/näheres*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Der Satz "Stell die Blumenvase näher an die Mitte vom Tisch" ist korrekt.

Dein zweiter Satz geht aber nicht. Was gehen würde:

"Stell die Blumen näher in die Mitte" oder auch
"Stell die Blumen näher zur Mitte"

Das heißt dass man "näher" als Präposition + "zu/zur" verwenden kann.

Comment: *näher in die Mitte* funktioniert m.A. nach nicht (höchstens, du sitzt in der Mitte vom Tisch und meinst "näher zu mir" - "näher" ist immer relativ zu etwas und braucht deshalb ein "zu", oder ein "an", um die relative Position zu beschreiben ("in die Mitte" beschreibt keine relative Position). Wenn es fehlt, nimmt man automatisch an, du meinst "zu mir" - Wie in "komm näher" oder "treten Sie doch näher"

Comment: In "näher" + "zu/zur" ist "näher" ein Attribut zur Präpositionalgruppe. Vergleiche: "_Ganz_ in meinem Sinne", "_höchstens_ im Notfall", "_oben_ auf der Leiter".

Answer (score 1):

›Näher‹ ist ein Adjektiv (im Komparativ) und kann natürlich als Adverb gebraucht werden – genauso, wie ein Adjektiv als Substantiv gebraucht werden kann (Substantivierung):

Die schöne Frau.

-->   Ich liebe das Schöne.

Vgl.: Ich liebe das Licht.

Er ist ihr näher.

-->   Ich gehe näher zur Mitte.

Vgl.: Ich gehe jetzt zur Mitte.

---

›Ich stelle die Blumen näher zur Mitte‹ ist wohl die beste Version, man kann es – holprig – auch näher an die Mitte stellen.

Als Präposition kann man es nicht verwenden.

Answer (score 1):

Da etwas [nahe](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nahe_bei_unweit) der Mitte sein kann, kann man es auch näher der Mitte stellen. Wie Du an den anderen Antworten siehst, klingt das etwas gekünstelt.

Comment: ›Nah(e)‹ ist eine Präposition, aber ›näher‹ (und andere Formen des Adjektivs ›nah(e)‹) eben nicht. Genauso wenig sind ›lauter‹ und ›kräfte‹ Präpositionen.